# Parse Dashboard Automatically deleted installation table data

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, push-notification

I have installed parse server and parse dashboard on my own server since 2.5 month for sending push notification purpose. I was shocked when I saw yesterday the installation table is empty. I also checked today then It is same thing happened again. (Before Today all table data are empty)

Ex.
Yesterday I have 100 records, today I check all record of past is empty and now I can see only today records only. Means every day past records delete from parse server.

As I have checked Mongodb connection but it is working fine since last 2.5 months. Could suggest me what is going wrong with parse.Please update fast as my project is live and I am not able to send push notification.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have a standalone mongo database?

Comment: yes I have mongo db

Comment: Can you share the version details of both parse-server and the Dashboard.

Comment: also are you only using the _Installation table?

Comment: yes we use only _installation table

Comment: Parse server version - 2.2.7 , Dashboard version - 1.0.80

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you update that all!

Comment: same here :( any solution?